# Delete duplicate pair of rows in excel by comparison

Tags: excel, vba

I have data arranged in two columns like columns A and B in the picture. I want to delete certain pairs (rows) from the data. The pairs to be deleted are given in columns E and F.

I am looking for a formula (or group of formulae) that can take information from column E and F and delete the respective pair from column A and B and shift cells up. Actual data has 7000 rows and to be deleted rows are near 200.

I tried Conditional Formatting or Advanced Filter (It gives only headers when  I select Unique Records Only) but nothing seems to work.

I have no knowledge of VB. So formulae/commands would be preferred if possible, please. Many Thanks for the help.

Before Removing Rows :

[image: Before Removing Rows]

After Removing Rows :

[image: After Removing Rows]

Comment: It is possible with formulas but - in my opinion - very complex and either with very long formulas or 2-3 helper columns. VBA on the other side will be easy and readable.

Comment: You can try to record macro by yourself and use Basic Filter: apply filter to both columns A and B, set first value from column E to filter in column A, same thing for columns F and B. If there is a record on your filtered table, this is the one you want to delete. Delete these cells, shifting other cells up. Then check the recorded macro and try to improve it. Come back in case you will need help.

Comment: you can use `vlookup` to mark which records to delete? I can provide you the method if this will solve your problem

Comment: I am trying to do it using `vlookup`. I will get back with whatever I achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:
**(1)**: Concatenate columns A and B using `A2&" "&B2` with result in `C2`.
**(2)**: Likewise concatenate columns E and F.
**(3)**: In column D Use the formula: `IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C2,$I$4:$I$5,1,0)),"No", "Yes")`. It will compare two columns and print "Yes" for any value that matches and "No" if it doesn't. The formula is taken from the page [link](https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vlookup-in-excel/#Vlookup-Multiple).
**(4)**: Sort data in column D.
**(5)**: Delete the rows with "Yes".
**(6)**: Separate columns A and B again.

[After Steps 1 - 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5moWr.jpg)

Comment: @Monah: Thanks for the idea. I am sure there are better solutions possible. Kindly please do share if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for just giving out a link to help. I forgot that it can be change anytime in the future. So here's the full steps that you are going to make in order to solve your problem.

Steps:
[Use Conditional Formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmsDL.jpg) 
[Use Filter function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPz4L.jpg)
[Use Filter Color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bn2Gs.jpg)
[Now you're done.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFSxn.jpg)

Sorry if I can't embed the picture here because my reputation is still low. But give me a chance to help just like this. I deleted my previous post by the way. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is, I do have repeated entries in both columns individually but no pair (row values together in columns A & B as a pair) repeats through out the data. It is not about repetition in individual columns. Selected pairs are to be deleted, and the selection has to be made from columns E and F. I hope its clear. Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: I notice it just now that what I give you will not help on your case. Vlookup is that answer to your problem maybe but I'm not so much familiar with it. Hope someone could help you. Have a good day!